# Can i scroll to left in testcafe

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe for create automation script but we have a table and have 3 first table is freeze so table behind is using scroll left or right to see that.
Not sure that testcafe have support scroll to left or right

Answer (score 0):

You can use [t.scroll](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403065/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scroll), [t.scrollby](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403066/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scrollby), or [t.scrollIntoView](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403067/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scrollintoview) methods to scroll elements both horizontally and vertically.